# no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer, rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been getting this error, no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer. I searched for this error but don't really understand it. Code is at the bottom. Once it gets to this "if q[:text_field].is? Array" that is when it gives the error and I'm sure that the rest of that code is wrong. But no idea how to fix it.

```
pages = Vovici::API.new(@pid).survey_structure
```

This is a sample of the api data that I'm calling with the code above.

```
[{:q_fill_in=>
 {:heading=>{:text=>"1"},
  :instructions=>{:text=>nil},
  :body=>{:text=>"Pac"},
  :list_caption=>{:text=>{:@type=>"plain"}},
  :total_label=>{:text=>"Total"},
  :text_field=>
   [{:label=>{:text=>"first"},
     :preselection=>{:text=>{:@type=>"plain"}},
     :symbol=>{:text=>{:@type=>"plain"}},
     :@id=>"1",
     :@dbheading=>"Q1_1",
     :@row=>"0",
     :@size=>"20",
     :@xmltype=>"text",
     :@required=>"false",
     :@compare_expression=>"-1",
     :@topic_first=>"true",
     :@slider=>"false",
     :@sliderstep=>"1",
     :@published=>"true",
     :@usecalendarpopup=>"true",
     :@insert_symbol_left=>"false",
     :@label_width=>"3",
     :@text_area_width=>"9"},
    {:label=>{:text=>"id"},
     :preselection=>{:text=>{:@type=>"plain"}},
     :symbol=>{:text=>{:@type=>"plain"}},
     :@id=>"2",
     :@dbheading=>"Q1_2",
     :@row=>"0",
     :@size=>"20",
     :@xmltype=>"text",
     :@required=>"false",
     :@compare_expression=>"-1",
     :@topic_first=>"true",
     :@slider=>"false",
     :@sliderstep=>"1",
     :@published=>"true",
     :@usecalendarpopup=>"true",
     :@insert_symbol_left=>"false",
     :@label_width=>"3",
     :@text_area_width=>"9"}],
  :@dbheading=>"Q1"}
```

This is code from my rb file

```
def process 
  pages = Vovici::API.new(@pid).survey_structure
  pages.each do |page|
    if page[:q_fill_in]
    process_fill_in(*page[:q_fill_in])
    end
  end
end

def process_fill_in(*questions)
  questions.each do |q|
    if q[:text_field].is? Array
      sub_qs = q[:text_field]
    else
      sub_qs = [q[:text_field]]
    end
    q_text = clean_question_text(q[:body][:text])
    sub_qs.each do |sq|
      sub_text = clean_question_text(sq[:label][:text])
      q_name = [q_text, sub_text.reject { |i| i.nil? || i.empty? }.join("--")]
      @survey.questions.create!(qheader: sq[:@dbheading], qtext: q_name)
    end
  end
end

def clean_question_text(text)
  match = /(&nbsp;)?(<.*?>)?(.+)(&nbsp;)?(<\/.*>)?/.match(text)
  match[3]
end
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you've used `[]` on an array but you've passed something that doesn't make sense to an array. In this particular case it's telling you that `q` which you are trying to use as a hash is in fact an array.

This is happening because `process_fill_in(*page[:q_fill_in])` is turning the hash into an array of key-value pairs (because of the *). I'm not sure why you've got a splat there at all.

Comment: I did it this way because from the api data you see an array of hashes but obviously this is wrong. Do you have any suggestions on what i can do to fix it.

Comment: As far as I can tell you don't need that splat at all (and probably not in process_fill_in either).